# Rails Best Practice to Reformat an Object for display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice to reformat an object for display?

I can do the below using nested .each statements in the view, but that results in a lot of DB queries. I'm assuming there is a better way. Would it be best practice to reorganize and sum my Entries in a controller and then just reiterate through that Object in the view. If so, how? Using map?

I have a Rails 5 object called JournalEntries (Entries for short). These Entries look like the following:

```
Date    Company     Account Amount
1/1/17  Foo         A       00.01
1/1/17  Foo         A       00.02
3/1/17  Foo         B       00.03
3/1/17  Foo         A       00.04
3/1/17  Foo         A       00.05
3/1/17  Foo         C       00.06
1/1/17  Bar         A       00.07
2/1/17  Bar         B       00.08
2/1/17  Bar         B       00.09
```

When I display these Entries, I want to group them by Company, then by date, then Account, then display the sum of the Account Amount. Here is how they should display:

```
Company 
    Date 
    Account Total(sum)

Foo
    1/1/17
        A       00.03

    3/1/17
        A       00.09
        B       00.03
        C       00.06

Bar
    1/1/17
        A       00.07

    2/1/17
        B       00.17
```

**UPDATE:** My concern is that I have 15 Companies each with 3 Account, where each Account has 10 or more Journal Entries. When the page loads, the console shows about 200+ Select statements since in the view I have 3 nested .each statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are actually two points to your question:

1. db hits: you can use eager loading to prevent N+1 queries. This can be done by using `#includes` (this does load all records into memory so if you've got tons of them you might need to do it in batches):

   `@companies = Company.includes(:accounts)`
2. where to put the presentation logics: just iterate through @companies in views for simple cases. But if you start to see complicated logics in your view, or you find yourself repeating certain patterns, you can refactor that into a helper (if useful across models) or a presenter class (useful for specific model/views). This way your views will be cleaner and it's also easier for you to do test in isolation.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should just continue to have nested .each statements in the view instead of reformatting the Object to multidimensional array in the controller?

Comment: In simple cases there's no need for that. But if it cleans up your code then by all means. Keep it simple.